# Ubuntu Gnome creates ~/Videos, ~/Desktop and ~/Public every boot

Tags: 13.10, gnome, ubuntu-gnome

My Ubuntu Gnome install creates the folders `~/Videos`, `~/Desktop`, and `~/Public` on every boot. I do not need these folders and they are cluttering up my home directory. What program does this? How can I prevent this?

**System info:**

- Ubuntu Gnome 13.10 (64 bit)
- GNOME Shell 3.8.4
- Linux 3.11.0-15-generic #23-Ubuntu

Comment: Not really sure but it could be xdg-user-dirs-gtk-update in start up applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable this feature

- system-wide: by editing the `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.conf` file and changing `enabled=True` to `enabled=False`.
- per-user: by editing/adding the file `~/.config/user-dirs.conf` to have the line `enabled=False`

Or if you only want to disable some of those directories but keep others then you have to edit the

- `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults` file for a system-wide solution. Just remove the lines you don't need. Or the
- `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file for a per-user solution. Here to disable a directory point it to the user's home directory, e.g. `XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME"`.

source: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-user-dirs/