# Public directory ($XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR) created despite "enabled=False" in user-dirs.conf

Tags: xdg

I've set "enabled=False" in my /etc/xdg/user-dirs.conf which, according to comments in that file, and also [according to the spec](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-user-dirs/#settings), should stop xdg-user-dirs-update from running at login time and thus also from recreating any missing $XDG_*_DIR directories.

Additionally, I've commented out the definition of XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR in my user's ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs due to not being able to decide where to point it at for now.

Despite xdg-user-dirs-update being disabled, a directory named "Public" reappears in my user's home directory at every login. What is causing this and how can I stop the unwanted Public directory from appearing? I've found [an old Red Hat bug referencing a similar issue](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=711132), but it's closed without a known fix.

The issue doesn't occur for $XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR which I've similarly commented out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue went away when I removed gnome-user-share (`sudo apt-get --purge remove gnome-user-share`). Apparently it was caused by Gnome's file sharing function referring to $XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR and recreating the (default-named) directory when not found. With gnome-user-share removed, the "Public" directory no longer reappears.