# How are the default user folders in the home created for a new user?

Tags: directory, home-directory, default

When a new user is created and it logs in the first time, those default folders in the home are created. How are they created?

If changing the scripts/configurations that create them so that they are not created anymore, would that cause a problem?

Comment: Related: [How do I make the public folder not appear in the home folder of new accounts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83283/how-do-i-make-the-public-folder-not-appear-in-the-home-folder-of-new-accounts)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The defaults can be examined using:

```
$ cat /etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults
# Default settings for user directories
#
# The values are relative pathnames from the home directory and
# will be translated on a per-path-element basis into the users locale
DESKTOP=Desktop
DOWNLOAD=Downloads
TEMPLATES=Templates
PUBLICSHARE=Public
DOCUMENTS=Documents
MUSIC=Music
PICTURES=Pictures
VIDEOS=Videos
# Another alternative is:
#MUSIC=Documents/Music
#PICTURES=Documents/Pictures
#VIDEOS=Documents/Videos
```

If you don't want a specific subdirectory created put a `#` in front of it to comment out the line.

The sub-directories aren't created until the user logs in with a GUI: [Create default home directory for existing user in terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335961/create-default-home-directory-for-existing-user-in-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

As @steeldriver commented, the answer is to edit `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults` so the variables point to your home directory.

Not sure about any problem this would cause.

Comment: Actually I think the right way to have them not be created would be to set `enabled=False` in the `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.conf` file