# How to get language variables (Desktop folder name, Document folder name, etc..)

Tags: bash, language-support

I am making a script and I am looking for a way to get the variable names for Desktop, Music, Documents, Pictures and others Folders. Depending on the language they change. For example Desktop in Spanish is Escritorio. So how can I get the folder directory without needing to find out what language the user is using or having to make several IF statements for each language.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a tool called `xdg-user-dir` that retrieves user directories paths

```
documents_path=$(xdg-user-dir DOCUMENTS)
echo $documents_path
```

From the docs:

> xdg-user-dir looks up the current path for one of the special XDG user dirs.
>
> This command expects the name of an XDG user dir as argument. The possible names are:
>
> - DESKTOP
> - DOWNLOAD
> - TEMPLATES
> - PUBLICSHARE
> - DOCUMENTS
> - MUSIC
> - PICTURES
> - VIDEOS

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, I don't really know if this is available in previous releases.

Comment: Thanks for this contribution! This ought to be the accepted answer to the question.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson What do you mean. This IS the accepted answer ^^. Excellent work Arge.

Comment: Great that you changed it, @LuisAlvarado.

Answer (score 4):

The common folder names are as follows. Just extracted from a file in home directory.

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

Of course, you are only interested in the variable name. So there are `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR, XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR, .... etc`.

Related question: [How can I change the default location of content directories (eg Pictures, Templates, Music)  in my home folder?](https://askubuntu.com/q/18103/61218)

Hope this will help.

Comment: Wow!. Thanks Anwar. Nice list. I got a little problem testing it. Doing echo on any of the variables throws nothing. I found the information in ~/.config//user-dirs.dirs but still the variables are empty.

Comment: same here, i also don't see those variables in terminal (at least not by default). 
localized folder names drive me absolutely crazy.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado @ritzikratzi the default method to change these variables in change in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file. and I think these variables aren't available from terminal

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there's an easier way to do it, but this is what i've done:

For example, getting desktop folder:

```
desktopVar=$(cat $HOME/.config/user-dirs.dirs | grep "XDG_DESKTOP_DIR")
desktopFolder=$(echo ${desktopVar/XDG_DESKTOP_DIR=/""} | tr -d '"')
echo $desktopFolder
```

For other variables is analogous.