# Storing files and folders inside 'C:/Users/UserProfile' and accessing from Ubuntu from second hard drive

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, hard-drive, windows-8, ssd

Windows8.1 is pre-installed in a 500GB HDD and then also installed Ubuntu14.04 in the second 256GB SSD for dual booting. Since planning to use Ubuntu as main OS, I want to store files in the larger space in the HDD while running OS from the SSD.

Now should I make a partition in the 500GB HDD for such storage purpose? If I make a folder, say 'LinuxStorage', as in 'C:/Users/UserProfile/LinuxStorage' and store all Linux files and folders in it, could it cause any problem? Thanks

Comment: What files you will store in? System or your documents? Just don't know your curren system partitioning.

Comment: PDF, documents, images, downloads etc. in the Windows8 HDD. The Ubuntu `/Home` in SSD is to be used for storing necessary coding tools and softwares.

Comment: So, yes, you can use it. Linux supports ntfs filesystem, since you not placed systems files in there it's ok to use Win 8 drive. Just don't place /home/, /home/user there, do symlink to your hdd or open it every time from file browser

Comment: More specifically, does it affect Windows performance if I need to use that OS? Any particular issues with permission when a file is created/edited in one OS and opened in another?

Comment: @user832 nope, it doesn't. Files and folders created with rules of filesystem. There is different implementation of fs drivers, but same rules at all.

Comment: This is not about relocating `/home`.  [This](http://askubuntu.com/a/267070/399438) answers it, even though it is based on another topic.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to boot live USB, and partition your 500 GB HHD to have an ext4 partition, say of 250 GB in size, and leave the other 250 GB for Windows 8. Once done, boot into Ubuntu normally, and find out the UUID of the partition that you created. For that , use `sudo blkid`, or `sudo blkid | awk '/ext4/ {print }'`.  Once you know it, edit `/etc/fstab` to be mounted on each boot; use [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions#fstab_example) as reference

Thus your files will be stored on that other hard drive, and under filesystem that linux understands, which should help you avoid any trouble. Something similar is done when [moving home onto separate partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving)