# Sound not working after moving /home to different partition. Works in log in screen

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, indicator-sound

System: Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.2LTS 64bits

Yesterday I migrated `/home` to a different partition using [this guide](https://www.maketecheasier.com/move-home-folder-ubuntu/). After rebooting everything was working great EXCEPT sound! I DO have sound in the log in screen, but once I log in there's no sound anymore and the sound indicator disappears. Upon opening the sound menu there's a bar, but no speaker icon. Using that bar doesn't do anything.

[image: Sound menu screenshot]

The sound configuration doesn't show any input or output device. This doesn't change whether I plug in headphones or not.

Running `pulseaudio -k` results in

> e: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such process.

Running `pulseaudio --start` results in

> e: [pulseaudio] main.c: daemon startup failed.

Running `aplay -l` returns this, which makes me thing ALSA is running, but pulseaudio fails.

> **** Lista de PLAYBACK dispositivos hardware **** tarjeta 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], dispositivo 3:
>
> HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]   Subdispositivos: 1/1   Subdispositivo #0: subdevice
>
> 0 tarjeta 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], dispositivo 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]   Subdispositivos: 1/1   Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0 tarjeta 0: HDMI
>
> [HDA Intel HDMI], dispositivo 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]   Subdispositivos:
>
> 1/1   Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0 tarjeta 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH],
>
> dispositivo 0: ALC269VC Analog [ALC269VC Analog]   Subdispositivos:
>
> 1/1   Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0

Running `pulseaudio -v` returns this

> I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NICE, (31, 31)) failed: Operation not allowed
>
> I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_RTPRIO, (9, 9)) failed: Operation not allowed
>
> I: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Successfully gained nice level -11.
>
> I: [pulseaudio] main.c: This is PulseAudio 8.0
>
> I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Page size is 4096 bytes
>
> I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Machine ID is 43726408b370455c9d7d6c6693a1e225.
>
> I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Session ID is 1.
>
> I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using runtime directory /run/user/1000/pulse.
>
> E: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Home directory not accessible: Permiso denegado

I went to `~/.config` and didn't find any pulse folder.

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems I messed something up with the permissions. I've updated the post with the output

Comment: I have seen the home directory, and it as well as everything inside it is owned by root and can only be modified by root. I attempted to change it using sudo nautilus, but as soon as I pick my user from the list it switches back to root. My guess is that this is because the partition filesystem is ntfs, and doesn't handle permissions the same way. The ODD thing is that I can normally open the file manager and create/delete files in directories owned by root without a problem.

Comment: Your NTFS partition is mounted and owned by root. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions but one reason why [you shouldn't have your HOME on NTFS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16038/using-a-folder-on-an-ntfs-partition-as-home) is what you observed now.

Comment: Woo hoo! I managed to solve it. Your command from the first comment made me realise it was a permission issue. From thereI went on and researched why I couldn't change permissions in the new home partition. Ifound out it was because I didn't include umask, dmask or fmask information in the fstab file. Now I included the parameters in the file and it is working perfectly. Thanks a lot. Without that command I wouldn't have noticed it wasn't just a sound problem. :)

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. Sometimes errors lead to the weirdest symptoms. If you like you can write this down in an own answer for others who face the same issue. Otherwise your Q should get closed as "off topic/solved on its own" ;)

Comment: I will. But I think I have to wait 24 or 48 hours? I also read on the site you linked that it's not recommended to use an NTFS partition as a home partition because of a lack of features. I am not having any troubles yet, but if something happens in the future, I'll know where to look at :)

Comment: I need a shared access from Windows, so I'll have to see how far this gets me.

Comment: Make it a shared directory on NTFS but only for those documents you need to share. In your HOME you can then point a dynamic link to this directory.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/223655/windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-share-files-between-os

Comment: I did that before moving the whole thing to the partition. But I thought it'd be easier to have config files there too, as well as .wine which becomes quite heavy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Takkat comment I realised this was a permissions issue. I was using an NTFS partition as a `/home` partition, and the `/etc/fstab` file was missing info about how to mount the partition, so it was owned by root.

I managed to solve it modifying the fstab file with `sudo nano /etc/fstab` and adding `uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=xxx,fmask=yyy` (the values you choose would depend on what restrictions you want to apply to the partition).

For those interested in how *mask work, check out [this article](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1453342&p=9115998#post9115998).